# I like to see you OR I like see you. Which sentence is correct? Can we omit "to" or not?

Tags: grammar

Which sentence is correct?

> I like to see you

OR

> I like see you.

Answer (score 2):

"I like to see you" is the correct way of phrasing the sentence. However, one may say "I like seeing you." One cannot omit the word to as it is part of the adverbial phrase "to see". In the second example "seeing" is a gerund acting as the noun object of like.

Comment: I feel "I like to see you" and "I like seeing you" are little different in meaning. If so, can you explain it a little bit? thanks!